# Weebly: Edit individual elements in navigation bar

Tags: css, menu, nav

I'm trying to edit the border-top of each element in the navigation bar in weebly so that I can style each of them a different color. However, when I jump into the HTML file, I only see "{menu}" within the navigation div. I want to be able to ID out each individual element so that I can style it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I used :nth-child(). Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide an example of how you were able to edit individual navigation items in Weebly using nth-child()?

Here is the code from my Weebly site, but I can't get it to work. I'm just trying to round the  top-left corner on the first menu item of the navigation bar. Right now, when I click on a different item, it shows it with a rounded corner on the top left. I always want the top left corner to remain rounded. I'm a newbie...

```
#topnav {
clear: both;
margin: 70px 0 0 150px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

#topnav ul {
list-style: none;
background: #404040;
width: 504px;
float: left;
}

#topnav li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 auto; 
}

#topnav a {
float: left;
display: block;
color: #fff;
background: #404040;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding: 16px;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 1em;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
}

#topnav li#active a {
color: #fff;
background: #8fa944;
}

#topnav a:hover {
color: #fff;
background: #8fa944;
}
```